# _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value) from SQFLITE Flutter

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I am trying to call this fetchall() method from totalprice() method, but every time it throws this error.
[image: SqfLite Error]

Here is my fetchall() method -

```
    Future<List<CartModel>>? fetchall() async {
    List<Map<String, Object?>>? map = await database?.query(tablename);
    List<CartModel> cartproducts = [];
    CartModel singleproduct = CartModel();
    
    for (Map<String, Object?> i in map!) {
      cartproducts.add(CartModel.fromJson(i));
      singleproduct = CartModel.fromJson(i);
      a = a + singleproduct.price!.toInt();
    }
    
    return cartproducts;
```

and this is the totalprice() method -

```
      Future<int> totalprice() async {
        int totalprice = 0;
        List<CartModel>? products = await fetchall();
        if (products != null) {
          for (var i in products) {
            totalprice = (totalprice + i.price!.toInt() * i.quantity!.toInt());
          }
        }
        return totalprice;
```

**Thanks for any little help.**

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```dart
List<Map<String, Object?>>? map = await database?.query(tablename);
```

Is probably assigning a `null` value to your `map` variable which your are later using with a null check operator `!` which means that you are sure that it's not null, but the type `List<Map<String, Object?>>?` in the mentioned line gives it the ability to be null.

You can solve this by adding a null check before using the `map` variable like so

```dart
Future<List<CartModel>>? fetchall() async {
    List<Map<String, Object?>>? map = await database?.query(tablename);
    List<CartModel> cartproducts = [];
    CartModel singleproduct = CartModel();
    
    if(map != null)
     for (Map<String, Object?> i in map!) {
       cartproducts.add(CartModel.fromJson(i));
       singleproduct = CartModel.fromJson(i);
       a = a + singleproduct.price!.toInt();
     }
    }
    
    return cartproducts;
}
```

---

#### Additional advice

For better code quality and readability, please follow variable naming conventions. For dart, make sure are your variables and methods are [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)

so instead of `fetchall` => `fetchAll`

instead of `cartproducts` => `cartProducts`

instead of `singleproduct` => `singleProduct`

And so on...

Comment: Hey Roaa, thanks a lot for the solution. I haven't tried it out but I definitely will and I hope it works. About the code quality... yes ik that the way I write looks kinda ugly. I had this habit of writing everything in lower case because I used to code C++ a lot without following any particular practice :D and also feel lazy to tap 'shift' :D but yes I should follow the variable naming conventions. Thanks.